# How do I find all *.resx file that have an action type of integrate or edited from a Perforce change list?

Tags: version-control, perforce

I wish to do some checks on the results of a large merge, I know merges often get incorrect results with WinFrom UIs, so I wish to get a list of the files that need checking…

I can’t find a “report” option on any of the Perforce menus, the change list dlg also does not have an “expert” button, so I can’t get the data into excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> p4 describe -s 47773 | find /V "branch" | find "resx"

On the windows command line got me a useful list.  (Where 4773 is the change list number)